# Variant of the knapsack problem and box stacking

Tags: dynamic-programming

I'm facing a problem described as follows:

You are given a set of $n$ types of rectangular 3-D boxes, where the i-th box has height $h_i$, width $w_i$, depth $d_i$ and value $v_i$. You want to create a stack of boxes with a height limit $H$ and maximize the sum of the values, but you can only stack a box on top of another box if the dimensions of the 2-D base of the lower box are each larger or equal than those of the 2-D base of the higher box. Of course, you can rotate a box so that any side functions as its base. You are also allowed to use multiple instances of the same type of boxes.

I realized that it is a combination of the knapsack problem and the box stacking problem with small variations. I tried to solve it using the knapsack algorithm adding the box stacking restrictions, but I'm not getting the right results. Does anyone know a similar problem or could indicate me an algorithm? I have to implement it using dynamic programming.

Comment: If you can use multiple instances of the same box, and we only require that the box below a box is larger than *or equal to* it, then you can get infinite value by picking any box with positive value and stacking an infinite number of copies of it on top of itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good dynamic programming exercise.  Here's a hint.

> Let $f(i)$ denote the maximum height that can be achieved if you have the $i$th box at the bottom.  Can you find a recursive relation to let you compute $f$ in a recursive fashion?

Think about that one.  If you get stuck, here's another hint:

> Oops, you'll probably discover that doesn't quite seem to work.  What additional information would we like to know about the box at the bottom, to enable you to find a recursive relation?  You might need to add an extra parameter to $f$, so it becomes $f(i,\text{something})$ -- what should you put as the "something"?

If you can answer those hints, you should be very close to finding a dynamic programming algorithm for the problem.